# Char Sequence to Hierarchical JSON - d3.sunburst

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js

I have been given an array of many different char patterns, see `data` below, and I am trying to nest the data into a hierarchical JSON form for insertion into a sunburst visualization. Each pattern is made up of `n` characters, although the ones below are 8 characters. To talk through the desired result:

1. At level 0, find how many unique chars there are. Answer: ['w', 'm'].
2. Take the first key 'w' and find all the unique chars that are at level 1 then go to level 2, and so on until hitting the end of a pattern wherein we calculate the size of that unique pattern at the end.
3. Repeat #2 for the second key 'm'
4. Insert the result into the `children` property of `root`.

I was able to construct code for the two level case and could subsequently go deeper with much nesting, but it would be very hardcoded and super difficult to understand. Does anyone know of a way I could do this recursively or with another pattern that would solve it?

Desired Output Sample:

```
var root = {"name":"evt_seq","children":[{"name":"w","children":[{"name":"w","size":8},{"name":"k","size":1}]},{"name":"m","children":[{"name":"w","size":1}]}]}
```

Two Level Nesting (Looking for n Level Nesting)

```
"use strict";
var data = [{"match": ["w", "w", "l", "w", "w", "w", "t", "w"]}, {"match": ["w", "k", "w", "A", "w", "w", "w", "w"]},
{"match": ["w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"]}, {"match": ["w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"]},
{"match": ["w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"]}, {"match": ["m", "w", "v", "v", "t", "m", "l", "m"]},
{"match": ["w", "w", "w", "l", "w", "w", "l", "l"]}, {"match": ["w", "w", "z", "w", "w", "m", "l", "w"]},
{"match": ["w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"]}, {"match": ["w", "w", "m", "w", "l", "w", "w", "w"]}
];

var root = {
    "name": "evt_seq", children: []
};
// Get initial pattern
var groupedXs = _.groupBy(data, function (d) {
    return d.match[0];
});
_.forEach(_.keys(groupedXs), function (d) {
    let _x = groupedXs[d];
    let _groupedXs = _.groupBy(_x, function (f) {
        return f.match[1];
    });
    let _children = _.map(_.keys(_groupedXs), function (f) {
        return {'name': f, 'size': _groupedXs[f].length}
    });
    root.children.push({"name": d, children: _children});
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(root));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely solved best with a recursive algorithm. Since syntax seems less important, I'll just give brief psudeo-code:

```
function subTree(inputs) {
    var children = []
    var leadingLetters = //map first letter from each array, remove duplicates
    for leadingLetter in leadingLetters {
        var matchingInputs = //filter inputs that match the first letter
        var reducedInputs = //copy of matchingInputs, but the first (matching) element is removed from each array
        children.push(subTree(reducedInputs))
    }
    return children
}
var root = subTree(data);
```

I didn't handle empty children array as being null, as I'm not totally sure what is expected when you reach the end of the strings. Either way, this should get you on your way. (PS Hope this wasn't for a homework assignment! =X)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Acey!

Answer (score 0):

@Acey - great guidance! See below for the fully working implementation. Thanks again and it's for a personal project and not homework :)

```
function subTree(inputs) {
    var children = [];
    var leadingLetters = _.uniq(_.map(inputs, function (d) {
        return d.match[0];
    })); //map first letter from each array, remove duplicates
    _.forEach(leadingLetters, function (leadingLetter) {
            var matchingInputs = _.filter(inputs, function (d) {
                return d.match[0] == leadingLetter;
            }); //filter inputs that match the first letter
            var reducedInputs = _.map(matchingInputs, function (d) {
                return {"match": d.match.slice(1, d.match.length)};
            }); //copy of matchingInputs, but the first (matching) element is removed from each array
            if (!reducedInputs[0].match.length) {
                children.push({name: leadingLetter, size: reducedInputs.length});
            }
            else {
                children.push({"name": leadingLetter, children: subTree(reducedInputs)});
            }
        }
    );
    return children
}

var root = subTree(data);
```